# Compare 2 large folders

Tags: powershell

I know there are a lot of questions asked/answered related to this but my question has twists.

So I'm comparing 2 folders that has huge amount of data (over 20gb and can go up to 40gb) one of them being OneDrive.

I'm trying to compare and find the missing ones along with which ones are newer. I can accomplish either or but regardless which one I try because the folders are huge, it takes a long time and sometimes even crashes. On top of that, when you run the script, it tries to download the files on OneDrive (even tho they are present when you do Test-Path.

I found a post that does both (link below) but wondering if there is  an easier way to accomplish this without downloading or putting it in a variable?

Thank you everyone in advance!

https://serverfault.com/questions/532065/how-do-i-diff-two-folders-in-windows-powershell/637776?newreg=b08ad3ef3c8e45d48ac0d17676a28df4

Comment: i would take a look at `robocopy`. you can tell it to only show what it WOULD do ... and save that to a log. plus, it is rather a lot faster than `Get-ChildItem`. [*grin*]

Comment: Agreed and I tried it and it works. But I need to get this done in PowerShell

Comment: you can call RC from inside PoSh ... and can convert the resulting log file into an object collection with a little bit of text parsing. [*grin*] plus, you can use the various RC options to leave out things that you don't want ... like the header & footer data. i usually just get the full file names, but you can tweak things as needed for most of the properties.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Sounds more work than what PowerShell can do (assuming...). I'm sure it is an easy solution just needs some tweaking with a new logic.

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] PoSh aint too good with large collections of files. you _may_ be able to use the pipeline to keep down the RAM use - it handles things one-at-a-time. however, i suspect that RC is likely to be your best bet for large file sets ... or a dedicated utility app. ///// i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

you can try with compare-object but you have to get all child items before like this:

```
$gci1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "Path to Folder"
$gci2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "Path to Folder"

Compare-Object $gci1 $gci2
```